# Paramater estimation in relative risk regression

Tags: regression, biostatistics, relative-risk

While reading a [study on leukaemia risk from ionizing radition](https://doi.org/10.1016/s2352-3026(15)00094-0), I am trying to understand how the model parameters are estimated.

The outcome variable $y$ in this study is binary (leaukaemia or not), and the predictor is continuous: the radiation dose $d$. The value of interest that is to be estimated from the observations $(x_i,y_i)$ is $p_i=P(y_i=1|d=x_i)$, or the relative risk
$$RR(x) = \frac{P(y=1|d=x)}{P(y=1|d=0)}$$
The authors use the model $RR(x) = 1 + \beta x$, which is equivalent to
$$P(y=1|d=x) = P(y=1|d=0)\cdot (1+\beta x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$$
Unfortunately, the study does not explain how the parameters $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are estimated from the observations. It looks like a generalized linear model of the binomial family, but, AFAIK, in these models an identity link function is not an option because it can lead to an infinite log-likelihood function. As a workaround, the link function $p_i=f(\beta_0+\beta_1 x)$ with
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
 0 \;\mbox{ for }x<0 \\
x \;\mbox{ for }0\leq x\leq 1 \\
1 \;\mbox{ for }x>1
\end{array}\right.$$
might be used, but as it is not differentiable the usual GLM algorithm for ML estimation does not work, I think.

It might be that a least squares method minimizing the estimated prediction error might work, i.e. minimizing $(\sum_i y_i-\sum_i p_i)^2$.

Does someone know how the parameters of this model are estimated?

Comment: Due to the simplicity of that example, you can probably just write down the log-likelihood and compute the MLE. No need for glm.

Comment: @lars-van-der-laan A problem is, that $(1-p_i)$ becomes negative for some terms, thereby rendering the log-likelihood function not computable. Using the link function does not help, because $1-f(...)$ is zero in these cases. The least squares approach is simple to implement and will yield a solution (Levenbergh-Marquardt), but I doubt that the authors of the study have implemented anything themselves. I guess they use some well known (yet not to me ;-) method and software library.

Comment: Yeah, that is a fairly common problem with relative risk regression. The most well-known relative risk regression method is the binomial family with the log-link function. Maybe that is what they use? It allows for a linear specification of the log RR. The intro of this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.02430.pdf discussed the method. The issue is that the log-link doesn't respect probability constraints and therefore typical glm solvers have convergence issues.

Comment: In the paper they explicitly give *no* link function, ie., their link function is the unity. Maybe the INWORKS data used in the study is available somewhere, and I can then try both MLE or generalized method of moments (GMM, the least squares estimator) to see if I can reproduce the reuslts. I have found GMM to yield results in cases where ML fails, so this indeed my be promising, and if both works, the results are rarely much different.